# How to create a Y/N flag in a data set for shared variables across STUDY in a data frame

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a YES/NO flag in a data set such that if a variable in `VARIABLE` column is present in every `STUDY` then YES, otherwise NO. so for example when AGE is present in all studies then the flag shoudl be YES otherwise it is no.

A simple example is here but my data is much bigger and has other columnes as well:

```
STUDY     VARIABLE
STUDY1      AGE
STUDY1      SEX
STUDY1       WT
STUDY2      AGE
STUDY2      RACE
STUDY2       WT
STUDY3      AGE
STUDY3      SEX
STUDY3       WT
```

Output should be:

```
STUDY     VARIABLE  FLAG
STUDY1      AGE      YES
STUDY1      SEX      NO 
STUDY1       WT      YES
STUDY2      AGE      YES
STUDY2      RACE     NO
STUDY2       WT      YES
STUDY3      AGE      YES
STUDY3      SEX      NO
STUDY3       WT      YES
```

How can i do that in R using `data.table' ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic to implement here? When do you have YES and when is it NO ? I don't understand what you mean by `if a variable in VARIABLE column is present`.

Comment: I edited the question and has put further explanation

Comment: Can a variable exist only once in a `STUDY` ? So `AGE` will only occur max 1 time and will not repeat in the study ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that a variable will exist in one study but not the other studies.

Comment: and Yes a variable exist only once in each study

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for unique counts of `STUDY` in each `VARIABLE`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df) #If needed to convert to `data.table`
df[, FLAG := ifelse(uniqueN(STUDY) == uniqueN(df$STUDY), 'YES', 'NO'), VARIABLE]
df

#    STUDY VARIABLE FLAG
#1: STUDY1      AGE  YES
#2: STUDY1      SEX   NO
#3: STUDY1       WT  YES
#4: STUDY2      AGE  YES
#5: STUDY2     RACE   NO
#6: STUDY2       WT  YES
#7: STUDY3      AGE  YES
#8: STUDY3      SEX   NO
#9: STUDY3       WT  YES
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
df[, n := (.N == 3), by = VARIABLE][, FLAG := c("YES", "NO")[match(FLAG, c(TRUE, FALSE))]]

    STUDY VARIABLE FLAG
1: STUDY1      AGE  YES
2: STUDY1      SEX   NO
3: STUDY1       WT  YES
4: STUDY2      AGE  YES
5: STUDY2     RACE   NO
6: STUDY2       WT  YES
7: STUDY3      AGE  YES
8: STUDY3      SEX   NO
9: STUDY3       WT  YES
```

If you need generalized way, please let me know(with specific condition will be grateful).

```
df[, FLAG := (.N == df[,uniqueN(n = uniqueN(STUDY), STUDY)]), by = VARIABLE][, FLAG := c("YES", "NO")[match(FLAG, c(TRUE, FALSE))]]
```

Comment: The condition is that, for example, when AGE is present in all studies then the flag should be YES otherwise it is NO. Same for all others.

Comment: @Amer I add new code above. It's more general than using 3. I'm sorry that it's messy.